Is it possible to hide payload details from curl section in swagger
I have an endpoint that handles login and logout. However on successful login, the username and password that is passed in the request body gets displayed in the curl section.
Is there a way to hide the login credentials(maybe remove the password) or hide curl section totally. A copy of the curl details below, I used 'string' for illustration purpose
curl -X 'POST' \  'http://localhost/api/auth/login' \
-H 'accept: /' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
"username": "string",
"password": "string"
}'
I have tried to use DocumentFilter but it does not solve it

Swagger shows you the curl command to execute the request, you still manually have to enter any and all variables required for the request, meaning you just entered your username and password in textfields on the swagger ui, why would you need to hide it from the curl command?

Could you please share the details codes you have used? By default, the swagger will not show the password or the username. Why you need hide it?
